# how to send image to email which is in tinymce editor

Tags: php, image, email, tinymce, justboil.me

I am using justboil.me image upload plugin in tinymce editor. now i would to send mail whatever is written or image uploaded it send to the user. Image stored in folder correctly. i am not saving image name in DB. 
Directly i am sending email.
If i want to save the image how to retrieve the image name ?.i am not receving the image in email.please help me out. how to get the image in email.

i added these lines in editor

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false ,
convert_urls:false,
```

In EMail Code is like below

```
    $emailmessage = $_POST['email_message'];
    $emailmessage=stripslashes($emailmessage);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Mail type `isHTML` set to `true` (or some parameter depending upon your mailer)?

Comment: i added these headers `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: where i need to set Mailtype `isHtml` set to `true`..?

Comment: Is it possible to send image which we uploaded in tinymce editor...please help me.

Comment: Yes, its possible. If possible just paste HTML body you are sending in mail.  and that isHTML i just asked to verify the mail type you are setting. Which is already you are following by setting `Content-type: text/html` so it should work.

Comment: where do i need to set `mailtype`

Comment: That is already set dude. You just post body of mail, the HTML you are sending. So that I can inspect problem from URLs of image, (if any)

Comment: `mail($email,$mailsubject,$emailmessage,$headers);` $emailmessage means whatever i get in editor.

Comment: is that wrong... i am unable to get your point

Comment: That isn't wrong. I'm asking about content of `$emailmessage` variable. Please post it in your question.

Comment: Now image div is diplayed in Email. but image is not displayed. what i need to remove in these urls `relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false ,
convert_urls:false,`

Comment: I can't say anything as I'm not expert using that tool. Could you please post message being sent? 
or just forward that mail to my email id. I'l see output in mail.

Comment: i added the code.please see the code

Comment: Try removing `stripslashes()` function.

Comment: ok. i removed and tried. now i received in email **\"\"** instead of image